# How to count free rotatable bonds

Tags: medicinal-chemistry

I am having difficulties to count the number of free rotating bonds for the Lipinski and Veber rules. What are the rules in doing so?

[image]

In Vemurafenib (shown above), which bonds are considered rotatable? Do the sulfonamide N-S bond, or the single bond linking two aryl groups, rotate?

Many thanks

Answer (score 13):

The idea of a 'rotatable bond' is somewhat arbitrary, given that under the right conditions basically any bond *can* be rotated. When thinking about concepts in medicinal chemistry like rotatable bonds, its therefore important to make sure you're working with the definition used when defining the rule.

The original Veber papers (*J. Med. Chem.* **2002**, *45*, 2615) define what they consider to be a rotatable bond:

> Rotatable bonds were defined as any single bond, not in a ring, bound to a nonterminal heavy (i.e., non-hydrogen) atom. Excluded from the count were amide C-N bonds because of their high rotational energy barrier.

Based on this rule, the Ar-Ar single bond *would* count as a rotatable bond, as would the Ar-N bond. The sulfonamide is generally excluded for the same reason as amide C-N bonds (although I can't find a quote by Veber that actually discusses this).

In reality, these properties are usually calculated automatically, for instance using [ChEMBL](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/). 
[image]

Comment: To add to this resonance affects if a bond can rotate. An amide bond tautomerises into an imide readily so is planar and a amine substituent on an arene (e.g. aniline) is not fully sp3 (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aniline#Pyramidalization)